# Jest unit test failing with `ReferenceError` from NPM package module

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, npm, jestjs

I'm getting failed tests after installing an NPM package (one of my own packages).

Specifically, I'm getting `ReferenceError: cc is not defined`, with the stack trace leading back to one of the exports in my NPM package.

`cc` is an object from a game framework (Cocos2d-x)  that is included in my project locally.

The game framework is *not* included in my NPM package, but the package does reference the object with the  assumption that whatever project has the package installed will also have the game framework already included. So essentially, Cocos2d-x is a peer dependency, but is not listed as one since it's not an NPM package itself.

The code I'm testing in my project does not make any reference to the game framework. And the methods that I'm importing from my NPM package do not make any reference to the game framework. I'm importing these methods using destructuring (e.g. `import { helper1 } from 'my-package'`).

With that said, I wouldn't expect it to be an issue. But Jest doesn't like the fact that `cc` is referenced from an entirely different export on my NPM package (one that is *not* being imported into the file being tested). In other words, `helper2` is causing Jest to fail because it does reference `cc`, but `helper2` isn't being imported.

How should I go about fixing this error so that the tests pass?

Comment: It may help to see some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my specific case, the problem was in one of my exports from the NPM package that looks something like this:

```
// NOTE: cc is undefined, with assumption that any project installing the NPM package will have
// the required game framework
class BackgroundLayer extends cc.Node {}
export default BackgroundLayer;
```

The solution was to simply add globals to my project's Jest config, like so:

```
"jest": {
  "globals": {
    "cc": {
      "Node": null
    }
  }
}
```

What is still not clear to me at this point is if this is to be expected. In other words, if Jest should be failing a unit test that has nothing to do with a non-imported export.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to recreate an environment similar to yours and I haven't been able to reproduce this error:

---

```
/so
  foo/
    index.js
    package.json
  answer.test.js
  package.json
```

Here's the content of `./package.json`:
*(As you can see it has `foo` as a dependency)*

```
{
  "name": "so",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^24.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "foo": "./foo"
  }
}
```

Here's the content of `./foo/package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

And here's `./foo/index.js`:
*(As you can see `helper2` references a global variable that is not defined.)*

```
module.exports = {
  helper1: () => 42,
  helper2: () => cc
};
```

Now the test file:

```
const {helper1} = require('foo');

test('helper1 returns the answer', () => {
  expect(helper1()).toBe(42);
});
```

When I run the test (`yarn test`), the test passes with no errors or warnings. So it doesn't seem that Jest is bothered by having a method referencing a global object that is not in scope.

Perhaps you could leverage Jest configuration options:

1. [`globals`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globals-object)

   > A set of global variables that need to be available in all test environments.
2. [`setupFiles`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array)

   > A list of paths to modules that run some code to configure or set up the testing environment. Each setupFile will be run once per test file. Since every test runs in its own environment, these scripts will be executed in the testing environment immediately before executing the test code itself.

Comment: Thanks for setting up this environment. Your `helper2` export, although working, set off my "aha moment", leading me to discover the direct problem, which I've posted. Although, as mentioned in my answer, I'm still not sure if this failed test is to be expected.

Answer (score -2):

did you try to create a lite version ?

[Lite version](https://cocos2d-x.org/filecenter/jsbuilder)

there was a discussion on that in the cocos2d forum